# Eclipse organize import for static

Tags: java, eclipse, import, static

Any one know, is there any way to organize `static import` in `Eclipse`?
Like <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> organize import, we have any keyboard shortcut for `static import`

```
import static java.lang.Math.PI; // ==> any key board shortcut?
import java.math.BigDecimal;
```

**EDIT**

My Case:

In one of my program I require to initialize 30 fields with `Math.PI`, I have initialized like:

```
private double var1=PI;
private double var2=PI;
private double var3=PI;
// other lines skipped
private double var30=PI;
```

To do this, I used `Notepad++` to edit multiple lines at once using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>navigation arrows</kbd>, then inserted code in `eclipse`.
Now, I want to do `static import` for the `java.lang.Math.PI` field (ie. `import static java.lang.Math.PI;`) with keyboard shortcut that will fix imports for these 30 fields with single key stroke in Eclipse.

With `Content Assist` option I have to select `Add static import for Math.PI` 30 times, in my case.

Comment: "Organize imports" command includes organization of static imports. Which result are you trying to achieve? Which code do you want to have after pressing this shortcut?

Comment: I see. Deleted my answer as inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Favorites` it gives you the option to define things such as `org.junit.Assert`

Comment: I need direct key board shortcut, with `content assist` I have to select `Add  static import for Math.PI` for all places.

Comment: If you add it to your favorites, you can just start typing the name of the class you want to use and hit `ctrl + space` and eclipse will offer up the list of suggestions.

Comment: Correct. But my case is beyond content assist. I cannot type 30 times and every time do `Ctrl+space`.  Because to save time I used Notepad++ to type `PI` single time for all 30 lines. `Shift+Alt+navigation arrow`, Then inserted code to eclipse. So only I have asked for any keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're saying. But in this particular case, shouldn't static members be accessed statically, meaning `ClassName.attrName` or `Math.PI`?

Comment: Of course, you can do that way too. But, what is the solution for my case? Is it not possible in eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried the option: java->editor->save actions->organize imports. It may be help.

[this is a screen capture](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-VJJOG5kA5sU/VUr1-QwsiEI/AAAAAAAAAEw/TEfL4umbqk8/w700-h509-no/eclipse-java-save.png)

Comment: Again, it is listed only in content assist. But there is no short cut to import PI directly.,

Answer (score 0):

If you have several constants the implements-a-nonabstract-interface trick might do.

```
public interface MathEnviron {
    static final double PI = Math.PI;
    ...
    /** @since: 1.8 */
    default double sin (double x) {
         return Math.sin(x);
    }
}

public class SomeClass implements MathEnviron {

    ... dietAfter(sin(apple*PI));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+M</kbd> (Source > Add Import) can not only be used to add missing imports. It can also help with static imports. Executed on a reference to a qualified member (read Class.member), the refactoring will add a static import for the defining class and remove the class-dot expression.

For example, if you have

```
import java.lang.System;
class Example {
void someMethod() {
System.currentTimeMillis();
 }
}
```

Place the cursor on `currentTimeMillis()` and press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+M</kbd>. This will transform the code to

```
import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;
class Example {
void someMethod() {
currentTimeMillis();
 }
}
```

This feature has probably been here for a while and is documented and was announced in a New & Noteworthy. I only just discovered it the other day and found that it highly improves working with static imports. Maybe you find it useful too

[another great example with good explanation provided](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/12/how-to-do-static-import-in-eclipse-java.html)